# What if my implicit wait is 10 secs and explicit wait is 5 secs, will it wait for 15 seconds in expected conditions

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

When i write some implicit wait like 10 sec and then for a element i give 5 seconds time in explicit wait...then will the implicit wait become zero and only wait for 5 sec or it will add the implicit wait time as well means will it wait for 15 secs

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer you one by one:

1. Whenever you put an ImplicitlyWait Selenium will perform that wait after each action. So it becomes contagious.
2. When you put an Explicit Wait, those are defined as per certain conditions like "visibility of an element" within until block.
3. So each type of wait behaves in their own fashion just by the way you implement them.
4. Once you assign timeunits for each type of wait, they are followed in execution. They never gets added or substructed.
5. ImplicitlyWait is mentioned only once within​ your code. This instruction is for the Webdriver to follow. ImplicitlyWait have no effect on any element in particular.
6. Where as Explicit Wait is assigned to ask the Webdriver to wait for a defined time period (e.g. 5 seconds) with a until condition which specifies the state of an element (e.g. element_to_be_visible) the Webdriver should look for.
7. Now answering your question: 10 seconds ImplicitlyWait for a element is not a valid statement. Explicit Wait of 5 second you have to put for a certain state/behavior of the element (e.g. element_to_be_clickable). If the element doesn't shows that behavior within the defined time slot Selenium will throw an exception.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but still confused -- suppose for a element implicit wait is 10 seconds  and for the same element i have putted explicit wait 5 seconds, so just tell me  suppose he did not find the element within 5 seconds , will it throw exception or will wait till given implicit wait is not completed...